# What is a belief, and how does it differ from an opinion?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, philosophy-of-mind

While many theories in cognitive science rely on the concept of a "belief" I do not see much on the definition of a belief or how it compares to other mental states. What is a belief, and how does it compare to things like opinions?

Comment: Can you point to some times you see the reliance on a "belief" in cognitive science?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems more about general semantics than scientific terminology. English SE would be a better place to start imo.

Comment: Not at all. I am not looking for some opinion on the matter. I am looking for theory from cognitive science. You do recognize that cognitive science relies on the concept of a "belief" quite a bit, yes? How can you reject the question of how to define it, or at least recognize it?

Comment: @ReedRawlings, how about cognitive therapy?

I've got a book in front of me: "Cognitive Schemas and Core Beliefs in Psychological Problems." But does it address what a belief IS? Nope.

Comment: Looking into that book it's using the dictionary definiton of belief to address clinical interventions and how those beliefs and schemas might affect a individuals episode.

Comment: The differentiation between mental states that refer to the world, and their contents, as well as more general aspects of that relation, e.g. propositional attitudes, are subject to philosophy of mind and by many but not all cognitive scientists considered an important part of CS. I think that technically this is the place to ask but you might have better luck over at the Philosophy SE.

Comment: I'll wait a bit longer, and if I don't find a better response, I'll delete/close this question and ask over at philosophy.

Comment: I have to agree with @AliceD here unfortunately. As a therapist I look at opinions and belief systems, but to have a definition which is concrete is not available in my view (opinion). Belief **systems** are a different matter, but opinions can be formed from beliefs, and beliefs can be formed from opinions. Opinion can be belief(s) and beliefs can be opinion. The "differences" are very blurry to say the least. It is very definitely a case if semantics in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: This [article](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2005/jun/30/psychology.neuroscience) from the Guardian reviews research into what forms and influences belief, gives some make up of what a belief is, but I could not find a, and separate, scientific defintion.

A opinion is a judgement based on facts while a belief is a conviction based on personal values.

> An opinion is a judgment based on facts, an honest attempt to draw a reasonable conclusion from factual evidence. (For example, we know that millions of people go without proper medical care, and so you form the opinion that the country should institute national health insurance even though it would cost billions of dollars.) An opinion is potentially changeable--depending on how the evidence is interpreted. By themselves, opinions have little power to convince. You must always let your reader know what your evidence is and how it led you to arrive at your opinion.
>
> Unlike an opinion, a belief is a conviction based on cultural or personal faith, morality, or values. Statements such as "Capital punishment is legalized murder" are often called "opinions" because they express viewpoints, but they are not based on facts or other evidence. They cannot be disproved or even contested in a rational or logical manner. Since beliefs are inarguable, they cannot serve as the thesis of a formal argument.

[Colorado State University](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://writing.colostate.edu/guides/teaching/co300man/pop12d.cfm&ved=0ahUKEwi0g5W2t8zNAhUU_WMKHX2pDV4QFggdMAE&usg=AFQjCNG1OZds1IRV89vhBg6DJS_dNXgpDA&sig2=h0eoUytsSCROX6n76SzN_Q)

Comment: So "chocolate ice cream is better than vanilla" is really a belief, not an opinion. Is the definition of "belief" addressed in any cognitive science text?

Comment: I don't imagine there would be a need to define it. The term is used universally. And it's fairly unscientific itself.

Comment: I'm not a fan of vaguely defined terms. With the advent of fMRI, we have a great deal of ability to look at cognitive states. And differences in knowledge systems, belief systems, the transience of positions of truth, the influence of external stimuli, etc are all very important. 

Maybe there's a way to avoid it. I'll keep looking. Thanks.

Comment: I believe your the only person who finds the term vague. There is no need for cognitive science to define a term that is already defined and used in English language. Beyond that, you could argue that the lack of a definition  in a field so focused on defining human s points to the fact that the general use of the word IS the definition. I wish you luck.

Comment: @DanielGoldman, "*I prefer chocolate to vanilla*" is a statement of **fact**: everyone accepts as truth that chocolate *is* your preference.  That you prefer chocolate is an **opinion**: you are describing something about yourself, not about the ice-cream. But saying "*chocolate ice cream is better than vanilla*" is a **belief**: you are claiming that there are objective factors that make chocolate fundamentally better, and that other people are wrong to think otherwise. Compare with "*Many people believe God exists.*" (fact), "*I think God exists.*" (opinion), and "*God exists.*" (belief).

Comment: *"[An] opinion is a judgement based on facts while a belief is a conviction based on personal values."* The opposite can be true too. Opinions can be formed from cognitive disortions which lead to prejudice with very little to no fact at all